# Getting parse error in knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am trying to call some data through the url but I am getting parse error, and I am not sure what to do since there is no other error.

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    BASEURL = 'http://localhost:8888/ko';

    self.alldata = ko.observableArray();

    self.viewAllInvoice = function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: BASEURL + '/index.php/main/learn_Ko' ,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType :'json'
        })
        .done(function(invoices) {
            alert(invoices);
        self.alldata.removeAll();
        $.each(invoices, function (index, invoice) {

                self.alldata.push(invoice);

            });
    })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(status);
        })
        .always(function(data){                 
        });
    };
self.viewAllInvoice();
}


$(document).ready(function () {

    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel(), document.getElementById('loanersclub_wrapper'));


});
```

Added an alert function to alert invoices but it just displays me html template.

Comment: ... so what's the actual error message?

Comment: @dfperry i inspected the page, there is no error message, i just get a alert box open up  saying parse error

Comment: is that coming from the $.ajax().fail() alert call? we really need more info

Comment: @dfperry, the alert reaches done, so I guess its coming from ajax

Comment: Have you tried different browsers?  Some browser error messages are more helpful than others.

Comment: Check that the data being returned from the ajax call is valid JSON.

Comment: What is base url for? Do you request data from another domain? That you need to allow CORS (cross-origin).

Comment: @RoyJ yup, I debugged it, its a proper json format

Comment: @SteenTøttrup I am using codeignter for getting all those information , so I need to use BASEURL to get to the controller function to call those information